# Make an order from avg() function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm currently working on one Laravel app and I would like to have this one section where top rated books are shown. I stored my ratings in Rating model.
My idea was like this below, but, indeed, it didn't work. I would be really, really happy if someone answered me correctly.

```
$book = Book::all();
$ratings = Rating::where('book_id', '=', $book->id)->orderBy(avg('rating'));
return view('toprated')->withRatings($ratings);
```

toprated.blade.php

```
@foreach($ratings as $rating)
    {{ $rating }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a MYSQL function, use `orderByRaw`:

```
$ratings = Rating::where('book_id', '=', $book->id)->orderByRaw("avg(rating)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code like:

```
$ratings = Articles::where('state', '=', '1')
   ->select(array('ratings.*',
       DB::raw('AVG(rating) as ratings_average')
       ))
   ->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC')
   ->get();
```